# How should I structure my Qt based project so as to have a clean qmake generated xcode project?

Tags: xcode, qmake

If I add sources and headers in my .pro file that arn't in the same directory, the resulting xcode project groups the files by it's default Sources, Headers, etc. but then puts the files in a subdir of those folders indicating the subdirectory where the files are. This make non-flat projects look exceedingly ugly when generated for xcode (notice all the Qt examples are flat).

How do I prevent it from doing that? Or am I stuck with either an ugly xcode layout, or a flat project?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create your own *configuration features* for qmake by adding a new CONFIG argument variable in a *.prf* file.

Check out this [Qt wiki](http://wiki.qtcentre.org/index.php?title=Undocumented_qmake).

Also it looks like you can use different variable names to generate different group names in xcode.

I'm going to figure out both these methods and generate a nice report.